# Looking up a value in a range that is between two given values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=INDEX(SPEC!$C$5:$C$650,MATCH(B3,SPEC!$F$5:$G$5,0))
```

It works fine but `$F$5` has a value of 1 and `$G$5` has a value of 100. So, if I type anything in between ie: 2-99 then it doesn't work.

Is there a way of using `<=` and `>=` somewhere to get it to also look at the numbers between 2 and 99 as my current formula only looks at those cells I mentioned and not everything in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your exact workbook I have had to create a dummy version which may not exactly replicate yours (see below).

[image: Screenshot of my example workbook]

On the basis that there will only be one value that falls between `$F$5` and `$G$5` in your values range (in my case `D5:D650`), the following should work.

`=INDEX(C5:C650, SUMPRODUCT(--(D5:D650<=G5),--(D5:D650>=F5), ROW(A1:A646)))`.

**Explanation:**

`D5:D650<=G5 = {FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE...}`

Using two minus signs before this, transforms the result of “True” into a value of “1” and a result of “False” into a value of “0.”

So in the case of `D5:D650<=G5 = {FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE...}` it transforms this to `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0...}`

The next criteria `--(D5:D650>=F5)` equates to `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...}`

Finally the `ROW(A1:A646)` element, just creates an array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...}`

SUMPRODUCT is then used to find the sum of the product of the arrays e.g. for the first element of the arrays the product is 0*1*1=0 but for the fift element - the one that matches your criteria - the product is 1*1*5, which gives you your row number.

INDEX then gives you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm. I have encountered a problem for when I am trying to achieve this with more than one row of data. I want to paste a screen shot here but not sure how?

Comment: Do you mean when there is more than one cell in the range that is between those two values?

Comment: Wish I could add an image to this post to show you. I will try type it out.

OUTPUT #N/A     
      
      
  JOB           INPUT  START END
  8586 542515  544360 544400
  8584           542515 542516

Comment: If we use your example, I have other numbers under F5 & F6 eg: 2 $ 200

Comment: Post a new question with what we've worked out so far and include the screenshots in that. It might also encourage other users to suggest solutions.

Comment: Done. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022459/looking-up-a-value-in-a-range-that-is-between-two-given-values-round-2