# Looking up a value in a range that is between two given values round 2

Tags: excel

My initial question was answered here: 
[Looking up a value in a range that is between two given values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004331/looking-up-a-value-in-a-range-that-is-between-two-given-values)

But when trying to achieve the same result with more data rows than just one, I am struggling. Here is a screen shot :

[image]

So, if I type 542515 in, it needs to look at P5 and P6 / Q5 and Q6
and see that 542515 is job 8584 and therefore in the output it must show 8584. If I input between 544360 and 544400 then it needs to output 8586.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Are the ranges in columns `P` and `Q` overlapping, or can we assume that they are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Hi. They should never overlap.

Comment: Then my answer should work for you, unless you had something different in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If your ranges in columns `P` and `Q` do *not* overlap, then you can simply check the input value in `N5` against each range using an `IF` formula.  My `IF` formula defaults to a value of 0 if the input cannot be found in the range.  Then I `SUM` over the `O` column to find the job which matched.

[image]

**Formula in O5:**

```
=IF(AND(N$5 > P5, N$5 < Q5), M5, 0)
```

**Formula in O6:**

```
=IF(AND(N$5 > P6, N$5 < Q6), M6, 0)
```

**Formula in O8:**

```
=SUM(O5:O6)
```

Comment: Not sure if actually understand what overlap means.. Let me try explain a bit more of what I am trying to do. If I type in"544370" then I want it to check between 544360 & 544400 as well as between 542515 & 542516. If it is between 544360 & 544400 then the result should be 8586. If between 542515 & 542516, then the result should be 8584.

Comment: Hi. Yes, thanks you. I see it does it if I have both formulas you said in O5 and O6. Can it work only in O5 though doing the same thing? If I type 542516 into O5 I get a result of 0 instead of 8584.

Comment: The input should be entered into cell `N5` only.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I will only be able to check this file out again from Monday and I will then mark an answer with feedback. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Hi Tim. I know you said the input should only be in cell N5 but that isn't going to be how I need it. I will require up to 30 inputs that all need to do exactly the same thing as N5.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SUMIFS` formula if the ranges does not overlap

Example considering 544370 is mentioned in N3 cell
`O3=SUMIFS(M:M,P:P,"<="&N3,Q:Q,">="&N3)`

For non-numeric job value try this

`=INDEX(M:M,SUMPRODUCT(--(P:P<=N3),--(Q:Q>=N3),ROW(A:A)))`

Comment: Hey, this seems to be working. let me try it some more.

Comment: This works until I put a letter into it ie:8586B. Sometimes there will be a letter. As soon as I take the letter out then it works nicely. Is there a way to get it to work with a letter at the end?

Comment: The same formula suggested in your other thread seems to work fine here as well, with a little modification `=INDEX(M:M,SUMPRODUCT(--(P:P<=N3),--(Q:Q>=N3),ROW(A:A)))`. Check this once

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I will only be able to check this file out again from Monday and I will then mark an answer with feedback. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I have tried this and keep getting a result of "0". Not sure why?

Comment: is your input in N3?? It gives 0 if the input is not between any range. Its working fine with simulated data

Comment: Yes, it is. Well, I have tried to implement this outside of my test sheet into my actual sheet and N3 is now B6 but yes, essentially it is the same. I am also looking at data in another tab called specsheet 

=INDEX(SPECSHEET!$C:$C,SUMPRODUCT(--(SPECSHEET!F:F<=B6),--(SPECSHEET!G:G>=B6),ROW(A:A)))

Comment: I recreated it like yours in my test sheet and it works. So, there must be something wrong with either my new formula or the spec sheet perhaps.

Comment: Please check if the data range is in SPECSHEET is stored in text format. If so change it to number and check